# Number of roots of specific polynomial in C.

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm revising for an exam and this should be easy, but I'm not sure if I should use Rouché's Theorem or try solving it via 'traditional' integration along the logarithmic derivative.

What is the number of roots (counting multiplicity) of the polynomial $p(x):= z^5 + 11z^2 − 4z − 2$ in $B_2(0)$?

Comment: Use Rouche’s theorem.

Comment: Rouche is useful in exercises designed to use it. It is garbage otherwise. A combination of the argument principle and Sturm's theorem is much better. This particular exercise is designed, though. $|p(z)-11z^2|=|z^5-4z-2|\leq |z|^5+4|z|+2=42<44=|11z^2|$ for $|z|=2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we know that $p(z)$ does not have any zeros on $|z|=2$.

With $q(z):= -11z^2$ and for $|z|=2$ we have:

$|p(z)+q(z)|=|z^5−4z−2|≤|z|^5+4|z|+2=42<44=|11z^2| = |q(z)|$.

Thus, by Rouché's Theorem, the number of zeros times their multiplicities and indices of $p$ and $q$ in $B_2(0)$ is equal.

Because $q(z)$ has a zero of second order in $z=0$ and $Ind(\partial B_2(0), 0)=1$ the number is $2$.

Comment: You don't really need to assume that there are no zeros on $|z|=2$. The strict inequality that you proved ensures that that cannot happen. If $z_0$ is a root of $p$ and $|z_0|=2$, then $|q(z_0)|=|p(z_0)+q(z_0)|\leq 42\mathbf{<}44=|q(z_0)|$, which is impossible.